# PowerShell detect if command terminated

Tags: powershell

I have a long running script that runs as a PowerShell command for many hours. Occasionally it terminates - usually OutOfMemory. When this occurs the PowerShell window returns to `PS C:\XXXXX>`.

I thought simply I could have an additional PS window that listens if the other terminates in an effort to keep it alive. If the other PS window returned to `PS C:\XXXX` it could start the script again as a back.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `for() { .\Script.ps1 }`

Comment: Can you elaborate for me? if within this for loop it will restart if it fails?

Comment: It's just an infinite loop.

Comment: @PetSerAl if the script fails continiously powershell will close this infinite loop after some number of executions,

Comment: @PetSerAl and this doesn't take care if the script is successful,,, no matter what that script is supposed to run forever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the script invocation in a try/catch block to handle the OOM exception, then wrap that in a loop:

```
do {
    try {
        # Run the script
        .\script.ps1
        $Success = $true
    }
    catch {
        # Something happened, make sure we try again
        $Success = $false
    }
} while (-not $Success)
```